# error installing samba CentOs

Tags: centos, compiling, samba

I'm trying to install samba in a server CentOs 6.8, but send me an error :

> /home/instaladores/samba-4.6.3/source4/lib/tls/wscript:51: error: Building the AD DC requires GnuTLS (eg libgnutls-dev, gnutls-devel) for ldaps:// support and for the BackupKey protocol

So I tried to install GnuTLS .. but i got a new error :

```
server:/home/instaladores/gnutls-3.5.9 # ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
 checking whether build environment is sane... yes
 checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
 checking for gawk... gawk
 checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
 checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
 checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
 ***
 *** Checking for compilation programs...

 checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
 checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
 checking for gcc... gcc
 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
 checking for suffix of executables...
 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
 checking for suffix of object files... o
 checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
 checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
 checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
 checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
 checking for style of include used by make... GNU
 checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
 checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
 checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
 checking for ANSI C header files... yes
 checking for sys/types.h... yes
 checking for sys/stat.h... yes
 checking for stdlib.h... yes
 checking for string.h... yes
 checking for memory.h... yes
 checking for strings.h... yes
 checking for inttypes.h... yes
 checking for stdint.h... yes
 checking for unistd.h... yes
 checking minix/config.h usability... no
 checking minix/config.h presence... no
 checking for minix/config.h... no
 checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
 checking whether _XOPEN_SOURCE should be defined... no
 checking for Minix Amsterdam compiler... no
 checking for ar... ar
 checking the archiver (ar) interface... ar
 checking for ar... (cached) ar
 checking for ranlib... ranlib
 checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
 checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
 checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
 checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
 checking the archiver (ar) interface... (cached) ar
 checking for g++... g++
 checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
 checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
 checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
 checking for bison... bison -y
 checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
 checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
 checking whether to build with code coverage support... no
 checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles...yes
 checking for autogen... :
 configure: WARNING:
 ***
 *** autogen not found. Will not link against libopts.
 ***
 checking for inline... inline
 checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
 checking cpuid.h usability... yes
 checking cpuid.h presence... yes
 checking for cpuid.h... yes
 checking for struct iovec.iov_basea... no
 checking netinet/tcp.h usability... yes
 checking netinet/tcp.h presence... yes
 checking for netinet/tcp.h... yes
 checking stdatomic.h usability... no
 checking stdatomic.h presence... no
 checking for stdatomic.h... no
 checking for getrandom... no
 checking for getentropy... no
 checking for NETTLE... no
 configure: error:
   ***
   *** Libnettle 3.1 was not found.
```

I been searching in a lot of forums and I've installed all this things :

```
curl-7.54.0
nettle-3.1.1
nettle-3.3 gmp-4.3.1-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
gmp-devel-4.3.1-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpmdevtools-7.5-2.el6.noarch.rpm gmp-devel-6.0.0-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
gmp-static-4.3.1-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

but the error is still happening....

Does any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the dev libraries of [autogen](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autogen/)  and [libnettle](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/nettle/) or alternatively try disabling the gnutls a the moment of compilation, be careful to check what features you are limiting doing this. Apart of this, why dont try to  use the yum package installer of centos? This will solve dependencies an errors.

Greetings

Comment: because the server is located in a restringed network and isn't possible to connect to download things  :/

Comment: @alfredo: it's still probably easier to download all the needed RPMs from another machine instead of building it from scratch. More so once you have a need to update Samba, like today.

Comment: and can I get them only copying the  /var/cache/yum ??

Comment: the rpms you must install are (in my experience) : samba, samba-client and samba-common ,  try downloading the rpms and check the packages that are marked as needed, on the other hand if you can replicate the machine (I mean the OS installed) in another system and make trials there to know exactly what you want.